# How can I move a btrfs partition? (after resizing it)

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, resize, btrfs

Is it possible to move a btrfs partition (after I shrinked it)? (e.g. as described in [How can I safely resize (shrink) a BTRFS partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75120/how-can-i-safely-resize-shrink-a-btrfs-partition))

I need this to grow the partition before the btrf partition.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a GUI installed on the system in question, you can use [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-move-partition) from the Ubuntu repositories:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted

According to [GParted features page](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/features.php), it has move support for btrfs, provided btrfs-tools is installed.

If you don't have a GUI, you could just use the GParted Live CD:

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php