# Dual booting windows on linux

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04

After having some issues with Windows 10 that came pre-installed with my laptop, I had to completely scrap it and install Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS; but now, I want to get windows on dual boot just for gaming.
On searching online, I installed GParted to make a partition on my ssd for windows but I have a few questions on what I saw there

[image]

1. I read that Ubuntu usually installs on a ext4 partition and Windows, on a Fat32 one. Does that mean that `/boot/efi` is the Windows boot drive?
2. Where are the Ubuntu boot files then?
3. If `/,/home` doesn't contain Ubuntu boot files, can I back it up, unmount and partition it for Ubuntu and Windows then?
4. Also, what method of

I'm currently running on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: This may help. https://www.techsolveprac.com/install-windows-after-ubuntu-dual/

Comment: You did not use the standard ext4, but used btrfs file system. The ESP - efi system partition is for UEFI boot and has part of grub2's boot loader. Windows will normally install its boot loader into the same ESP for UEFI boot. Some file systems do not support shrink only enlarge, do not know btrfs detail. Have good backups. https://askubuntu.com/questions/75120/how-can-i-resize-and-shrink-a-btrfs-partition Windows in UEFI mode wants multiple partitions, so let it install into unallocated space. Be sure to boot installer in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used dual boot since Ubuntu 16.04. I have many experience of encountering broken grub and reinstalling OS.

I strongly recommend install them on separate drive and install them independently, which means install each OS with all the other drive unplugged. Each drive has their own EFI partition.

Also, I suggest Windows as first boot order in BIOS because Windows Update has high probability to destroy the grub.

I think a hard drive price is quite cheap compared with the time you spend to debug when the dual boot broken. I think it is ok to shrink the space from DATA drive and install OS in that space if you don't want to add another drive. Remember to backup important data all the time.